# Does a stored procedure called from another block the calling procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Going through a debug, and I'm wondering if this is the case.

Basically, this is what I have:

```
CREATE TABLE
    SomeTable (col INT PRIMARY KEY)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE
    Procedure_A 
    @var int
AS
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM 
            SomeTable
        WHERE 
            @var = col
    END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE
    Procedure_B
    @var int
AS
    BEGIN
        EXEC Procedure_A @var
        INSERT INTO
            SomeTable (col)
        VALUES
            (@var)
    END
GO
```

Can I be certain that `Procedure_A` is completed before the insert statement is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EXEC command is synchronous, which means the next statement will not start until the called procedure has completed.  What could happen though is if two separate sessions call `Procedure_B` at nearly the same time you could run into a situation where you have an issue because there is no explicit transaction around the call to `Procedure_A` and your insert statement.  So something like this could happen:

- Session 1 Calls `Procedure_B`
- Session 2 Calls `Procedure_B` with same value `@var`
- Session 1 executes `Procedure_A` and deletes the record
- Session 2 executes `Procedure_A` and the delete does nothing
- Session 1 executes the insert
- Session 2 executes the insert and fails with Primary Key violation.

This is called a race condition or race hazard.  You could avoid this by wrapping the contents of `Procedure_B` in a transaction.